# Writing database software in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, database, software-design

I have been a self taught web developer for a few years now, and usually use C#/ASP.NET, Python, and PHP. But I want to try to advance my skills by doing something more advanced. I am looking to try to build a database program like SQLite, or a mini MySQL sort of thing in C/C++ just to practice and learn new things.

***EDIT:***
  My project doesn't have to be a RDBMS. It can be something like a simple web server or something. Just something to see if I like doing that kind of thing more than web development.

However, I can't seem to find any kind of book or tutorials online that teaches this sort of thing. Does anyone know where I can find resources regarding this? I have a C book that teaches the language itself, but I learn how to think through things a lot better when I try to build something specific like a database engine etc. Thanks for any input.

Comment: This question is not very clear. Are you looking for a DBMS book? If you are looking for implementation details, the source code for SQLite is available on the [download](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) page.

Comment: "I am looking to try to build a database program like SQLite" - you want to design and build a RDBMS? For programming practice? Suggest you choose something less ambitious

Comment: Well I have gotten the source for both MySQL and SQLite. But was looking at something that teaches WHY doing certain things certain ways were better for performance,modularity,portability aspects for that type of program than other types etc or how to approach different aspects a certain way to achieve certain criteria.

Comment: @MitchWheat It doesn't have to be a RDBMS. Even something like a simple web server like nginx or a mini Apache. I just am trying different things to see what i like to do the best as far a programming is concerned.

Comment: Totally on topic, that's an awesome gravatar.

Comment: @keith.layne LOL thanks. Thats where I go to school. Although they sucked really bad this year. Hopefully since Hunter and Bray will both be playing again next year, well do a lot better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For literature I could recommend something like Accelerated C++ or Thinking in C++. I also recently got my hands on Code Complete, found it in a shelf at work, and it is as good as people say. Solid language agnostic advice.

Also you should separate C and C++, they may seem similar and people clump them together but it's really two different ways of thinking. Now the new C++11 makes the differences even more important to understand, C++ is just not C with classes.

Comment: +1 for Code Complete. That being said, it's more of a "learn to be a better programmer" book and not a "learn C" book that Corey seems to be looking for. Also +1 for separating C and C++.

Comment: Oh I definitely know the difference. LOL I was just referring to possibly using both to build the project. But thanks for the input. Ill definitely look into the items referenced.

Oh and @TaylorPrice, I was actually looking more for a type of "learn how to think like a better programmer" kind of book. I have C and C++ books. I need more of a "heres how you should go about thinking though a project" kind of reference if you know of any more that you could list. Thanks!

Comment: My min-understanding. Code Complete is a great book! My old company made every new dev read it within their first year.

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you try something a bit smaller like a ray tracer? Its very attainable to write a simple one that can produce some nice images, and its something you can come back to again and again to add features.

Comment: It's maybe not what the OP had in mind, but I like the idea, +1.

Answer (score 5):

You can read the book [Learn C the Hard Way](http://learncodethehardway.org/c/) by Zed Shaw. He teaches you how to write C using [Make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/) and [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). Later exercises have you write your own software package installer and a tiny web server. Best of all, it's free.

*Updated broke link*

Answer (score 1):

Bookmark this resource, http://nptel.iitm.ac.in/courses.php?disciplineId=106

This is often a great/massive start point for in depth knowledge about everything from algorithms, dbms, graphics to real time systems. Complete video courses/lectures or written course materials. A place to expand knowledge or get ideas.

For example you could check the video lectures about dbms development 
-> http://nptel.iitm.ac.in/video.php?subjectId=106106093

...Or why not this one about artificial intelligence -> http://nptel.iitm.ac.in/video.php?subjectId=106105077

No c/c++ examples but they drill down each part, patterns, strategy and algorithms.

...The only sad thing is that most professors speak in really bad English.

Answer (score 0):

Well after @MitchWheat said that even writing something like SQLite was pretty ambitious, I chose to try an do a little web server instead and found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409087/creating-a-web-server-in-pure-c) which included a few links for doing that. Thanks for the input.